# How long can a Microsoft Server CA be down before a cert will fail?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, certificate-authority

We are using self-signed certificates for internal development machines and other internal connection encryption.

The certificates were created using Microsoft Certificate Server.

I need to move the certificate server from an old DC to a new DC, I am wondering how long the certificate server can be unavailable before the certificate cannot be verified and connections begin to fail.

I don't believe it is immediate, but I don't recall for sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Certificates will begin to fail validation once the published Certificate Revocation List (or Delta CRL, if they're in use) expires or is inaccessible (make sure that not all of your distribution points are on the CA itself).  This will depend completely on your configuration, and may be anywhere from under an hour to several months.

The Enterprise PKI snap-in (`pkiview.msc`) is a good resource for checking the status and expiration times of your CRLs, and you can check their configured lifetimes on the CA.

For the standard CRL:

```
certutil -getreg ca\crlperiodunits
certutil -getreg ca\crlperiod
```

And the delta:

```
certutil -getreg ca\crldeltaperiodunits
certutil -getreg ca\crldeltaperiod
```

Comment: You can also disable CRLs, so it's possible the answer is 'never'.

Comment: @Chris S, Is that a smart thing to do though?

Comment: No. The answer then is "when the certificates expire". having a CA "off" is standard for enterprise roots (certify a sub-ca, then turn off the root ca). But the issued certificates also have an expiration date....

Comment: @Brettski You'd only want to not use CRLs if there's no expectation of ever having to revoke a certificate for any reason.  This is not the case in most deployments, it makes sense in some specific cases.

Comment: pkiview was not located on my server.  I was able to use certutil to discover a clr period of one week and delta of one day.  Thank you for the information.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by, "make sure that not all of your distribution points are on the CA itself".  I am not sure of what distribution points you are referring to.

Comment: @Brettski They are the "CRL distribution points" or CDPs.  By default the CRL is published to Active Directory, so you're safe if that setting's in place. To check, open the Certification Authority MMC snap-in (`certsrv.msc`), right-click the server in the left pane, open Properties, and click the `Extensions` tab; select CDP from the drop-down, and you'll get a list of the distribution points.  If the `ldap://` URL has the `Publish CRLs..` and `Include in the CDP extension..` boxes checked, then you're in good shape.